# Jump elements of a sequence in R

Tags: r, seq

This is a question from a starter in R.

Let's assume that I have a sequence from 1 to 100.
How can I select the first and second elements, jump seven following elements, then selection the tenth and eleventh, jump again another seven...and so forth.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `cumsum` and `rep` to create the relevant indices

Comment: `seq(1, 100)[c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 7))]`

Comment: @Sotos , worked nicely thanks.